# Scheduling Optimization Problem - 5 days/week

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

A 24/7 calling center works as follows: every agent works 5 days in a row and
has two days rest, e.g., every week works Tuesday-Saturday and rests on Sunday and Monday.

The numbers of agents working every day of a week should be at least given numbers d1, ..., d7. The manager wants to meet this requirement with the minimal possible total number of agents employed, by deciding what will be the days off of the agents. Assuming that d_i are large, so that we can ignore integrality restrictions, formulate manager’s problem as an LO program.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. This is primarily a question and answer site. So, if you have a question about the problem you have posted, you should state that question. You should also state what you know about the question, what you might have tried in attempting to solve it, and so on. Without these things, your potential answerers may not wish to waste their time, because of the risk of writing something you already know.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical set covering problem.

First, define all the possible shifts:

1. Shift $S_1$ has working period Monday-Friday,
2. Shift $S_2$ has working period Tuesday-Saturday,
3. etc.

Second, define binary variables $y_i$ that equal 1 if and only if shift $S_i$ is used to meet the requirements.

Third, formulate the objective function and the constraints:
$$
\min \sum_{i}y_i
$$
subject to:
$$
\sum_{i\;|\;j\in i}y_i \ge d_j\quad \forall j=1,\cdots,7\\
y_i\in \{0,1\} \quad \forall i\\
$$

Some explanations now:

- There is one agent per shift, so minimizing the number of shifts will minimize the number of agents
- The constraint ensures that the daily requirement will be met: for each day $j$ you sum over all shifts for which day $j$ is a working day, and make sure the number of agents is at least as large as $d_j$
- Finally, if you do not want to manually create the shifts $S_i$, you can add constraints to your program to create them, but that requires a little more work here.

Comment: thank you! this gave me a good starting position. I decided to use one decision  

variable $x_i$: number of agents beginning on day $i \in [1,2,...,7]$ 

and decided to minimize the total number of employees by optimizing over the feasible set subject to the total number of employees working on day i $<= d_j$ (hopefully i used mathjax correctly)